# about displayWidth and displayHeight in OpenDDR

Tags: java

Does somebody know if the properties `displayWidth` and `displayHeight` (in [OpenDDR](http://www.openddr.org/)) are in pixels or in millimeters? I tried to find the id but I am not successful.

I found it:  `displayWidth` and `displayHeight` (in OpenDDR) are in pixels

Comment: Zhivko: if you find the answer to your question, you should probably post it as an answer (yes, even if you asked the question yourself), so that others can quickly see the solution when they find your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found it:displayWidth and displayHeight (in Open DDR) are in pixels.